# How could I add a class for all the text input under one ID?

Tags: jquery

give all text input a class "form-control" under table with ID "table-form" using jquery

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="table-form">
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="right">ID:</td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['ID']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="right">Cid:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cid" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['cid'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="right">Text:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['text'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="right">Star:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="star" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['star'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Update record"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

give all text input a class "form-control" under table with ID "table-form" using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this.

```
$('#table-form input[type=text]').addClass('form-control');
```